# Media Notification not showed

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a notification always visible to play and stop a radio. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. So Here i post my code:

I don't understand if something is missing for the notification to be shown or if I build the notification badly. In any case, the service works correctly if I activate the radio from the button I inserted in the Compose part, and if I close the app everything continues to work correctly, but I would like to understand why there is no notification at the top which allows you to activate or deactivate radio

**Manifest**

```
<service
    android:name="com.example.appradio.services.MediaSessionService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<receiver android:name="androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**MainActivity**
Inside on create method:

```
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(
    this@MainActivity.applicationContext,
    Intent(this@MainActivity.applicationContext, MediaSessionService::class.java)
)
```

**Service**

```
class MediaSessionService : Service() {
    var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null
    private var mMediaNotificationManager: MediaNotificationManager? = null
    private var mediaSession: MediaSessionCompat? = null
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
        mMediaNotificationManager = MediaNotificationManager(this)
        mediaSession = MediaSessionCompat(this, "SOME_TAG")
        mediaSession!!.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS or MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS)
        mediaSession!!.setCallback(object : MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
            override fun onPlay() {
                mediaPlayer!!.start()
            }

            override fun onPause() {
                mediaPlayer!!.pause()
            }
        })
        val notification = mMediaNotificationManager!!.getNotification(
            metadata, state, mediaSession!!.sessionToken
        )
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
    }

    val metadata: MediaMetadataCompat
        get() {
            val builder = MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
            builder.putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, "artist")
            builder.putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, "title")
            builder.putLong(
                MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, mediaPlayer!!.duration
                    .toLong()
            )
            return builder.build()
        }
    private val state: PlaybackStateCompat
        private get() {
            val actions =
                if (mediaPlayer!!.isPlaying) PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE else PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY
            val state =
                if (mediaPlayer!!.isPlaying) PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING else PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED
            val stateBuilder = PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
            stateBuilder.setActions(actions)
            stateBuilder.setState(
                state,
                mediaPlayer!!.currentPosition.toLong(),
                1.0f,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
            )
            return stateBuilder.build()
        }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        if ("android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" == intent.action) {
            val keyEvent = intent.extras!!["android.intent.extra.KEY_EVENT"] as KeyEvent?
            if (keyEvent!!.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE) {
                mediaPlayer!!.pause()
            } else {
                mediaPlayer!!.start()
            }
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    companion object {
        const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 888
    }
}
```

**Notification Manager**

```
class MediaNotificationManager(private val mService: MediaSessionService) {
    private val mPlayAction: NotificationCompat.Action = NotificationCompat.Action(
        R.drawable.ic_play,
        "play",
        MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(
            mService,
            PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY
        )
    )
    private val mPauseAction: NotificationCompat.Action = NotificationCompat.Action(
        R.drawable.ic_stop,
        "pause",
        MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(
            mService,
            PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE
        )
    )
    val notificationManager: NotificationManager = mService.getSystemService(Service.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    fun getNotification(
        metadata: MediaMetadataCompat,
        state: PlaybackStateCompat,
        token: MediaSessionCompat.Token
    ): Notification {
        val isPlaying = state.state == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING
        val description = metadata.description
        val builder = buildNotification(state, token, isPlaying, description)
        return builder.build()
    }

    private fun buildNotification(
        state: PlaybackStateCompat,
        token: MediaSessionCompat.Token,
        isPlaying: Boolean,
        description: MediaDescriptionCompat
    ): NotificationCompat.Builder {

        if (isAndroidOOrHigher) {
            createChannel()
        }
        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(mService, CHANNEL_ID)
        builder.setStyle(
            androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                .setMediaSession(token)
                .setShowActionsInCompactView(0) // For backwards compatibility with Android L and earlier.
                .setShowCancelButton(true)
                .setCancelButtonIntent(
                    MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(
                        mService,
                        PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP
                    )
                )
        )
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mService, R.color.black))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_play) // Pending intent that is fired when user clicks on notification.
            .setContentIntent(createContentIntent()) // Title - Usually Song name.
            .setContentTitle(description.title) // When notification is deleted (when playback is paused and notification can be
            // deleted) fire MediaButtonPendingIntent with ACTION_PAUSE.
            .setDeleteIntent(
                MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(
                    mService, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE
                )
            )
        builder.addAction(if (isPlaying) mPauseAction else mPlayAction)
        return builder
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private fun createChannel() {
        if (notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID) == null) {
            val name: CharSequence = "MediaSession"
            val description = "MediaSession and MediaPlayer"
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
            val mChannel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance)
            mChannel.description = description
            mChannel.enableLights(true)
            mChannel.lightColor = Color.RED
            mChannel.enableVibration(true)
            mChannel.vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)
            Timber.d("createChannel: New channel created")
        } else {
            Timber.d("createChannel: Existing channel reused")
        }
    }

    private val isAndroidOOrHigher: Boolean
        get() = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O

    private fun createContentIntent(): PendingIntent {
        val openUI = Intent(mService, MainActivity::class.java)
        openUI.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
        return PendingIntent.getActivity(
            mService, REQUEST_CODE, openUI, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
        )
    }

    companion object {
        const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 412
        private const val CHANNEL_ID = "com.example.appradio.musicplayer.channel"
        private const val REQUEST_CODE = 501
    }

    init {
        notificationManager.cancelAll()
    }
}
```